# What is rootfs?

Tags: linux, fedora, rootfs

I'm a longtime Fedora user and I've just installed FC15. The new partition layout is confusing to me, as I'm used to the "plain vanilla" partitions that previous versions used.

```
[root@localhost ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                7.9G  596M  6.9G   8% /
udev                  496M     0  496M   0% /dev
tmpfs                 502M     0  502M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 502M  288K  501M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv00
                      7.9G  596M  6.9G   8% /
tmpfs                 502M     0  502M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                 502M     0  502M   0% /media
/dev/sda1             194M   20M  165M  11% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv03
                      2.0G  312M  1.6G  17% /var
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv02
                       20G  172M   19G   1% /home
```

I understand that the tmpfs partitions are mounted from an internal RAM disk. But what is this new rootfs partition and why does it appear to be mounting `/` twice?

Comment: Never understood why Fedora needed so many partitions, especially on a single hard drive system

Comment: These are not partitions.  They are filesystems.  The `df` tool operates in terms of mounted filesystems, and doesn't necessarily tell one anything at all (c.f. the LVM filesystems, here) about actual partitions on the disc.  For _that_ one uses tools such as [`gdisk`](http://rodsbooks.com./gdisk/) and `gparted`.

Comment: The default Fedora installation will just create the / filesystem plus the ramdisk ones. I created the /var and /home ones myself.

Comment: Similar on Super User: http://superuser.com/questions/576723/what-is-rootfs-and-what-can-you-do-with-it

Answer (score 19):

`rootfs` is a special `tempfs` image used in `initram`, and stays in this instance because you have an encrypted LVM setup. Normally, init would overwrite `rootfs` with the actual mounted `/` file system, but Fedora may not have that fixed with your setup. There is no harm in it.

see: http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a side-effect of symlinking `/etc/mtab` to `/proc/mounts` [as this forum post suggests.](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=263699)